# check if the query returns zero rows

Tags: php, mysqli

I am using this code, but I don't understand how to check if the query returns zero rows. How can I check that?

```
$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT ANNOUNCE_NUMBER,ANNOUNCEMENTS,ANNOUNCE_TYPE,POST_DATE FROM home ORDER BY ANNOUNCE_NUMBER DESC");

while ($obj = $results->fetch_object()) {
    //output results from database
}
```

Answer (score 37):

You can use the [`num_rows`](https://www.php.net/mysqli_num_rows) on the dataset to check the number of rows returned. Example:

```
$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT ANNOUNCE_NUMBER,ANNOUNCEMENTS,ANNOUNCE_TYPE,POST_DATE FROM home ORDER BY ANNOUNCE_NUMBER DESC");

if ($results->num_rows === 0) {
    echo 'No results';
} else {
    while ($obj = $results->fetch_object()) {
        //output results from database
    }
}
```